# How to use "foreach" and "first" together with a list?

Tags: list, foreach, netlogo

I am developing hospital bed occupancy model, wherein I'm trying to move AGENTS (patients and surgeons) in a specific order into the operation rooms (OR1). For this I created a separate surgery list1 (scheduled-surgery-list-OR1), I want to move the patient in who order whose time matches with the LIST2 (actual-surgery-list-OR1). I using below command, though it doesn't pop up any error but it's not working.

```
TO proceed-to-operation
ask one-of patients [
    foreach scheduled-surgery-list-OR1 [ num -> if num = who and ( position who scheduled-surgery-list-OR1 = position who actual-surgery-list-OR1 )
      [ ask one-of patients [ move-to patch-at 2 14 ] ]
      wait 2
 set scheduled-surgery-list-OR1 remove WHO scheduled-surgery-list-OR1 ]
 print "error" ]
```

Comment: Perhaps `scheduled-surgery-list-OR1` is empty? You could add a `print` statement to find out.

Comment: As an aside, this may not have to do with whatever your bug is, but using `who` numbers is almost always an unnecessarily awkward way to code in NetLogo and just makes your life harder. It's nearly always easier to reference agents directly and/or use agentsets.

Comment: Hi Seth, initially i make list empty and then lput who of patient ( SET scheduled-surgery-list-OR1 []     SET scheduled-surgery-list-OR1 lput WHO scheduled-surgery-list-OR1 )  so that all the patients move to the operating room in an order

Comment: What do you suggest to use to make patients flow in an order when their who number in both the lists matches, for an example a patient with who 2 in scheduled-surgery-list-OR1 and actual-surgery-list-OR1, should move to the operating room

Comment: I would suggest adding `print` statements to your code so you understand what it is actually doing. Once you understand what it is doing, either you'll see how it is different from what you intended, and you'll either know what to change, or you'll have a nice specific question you can bring here and ask.